# Seperating neighborhoods of infinite sets in normal topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(T,\tau)$ be a normal topological space, let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset T$ be a discrete subset. Are there disjoint neighborhoods $U_n(x_n)\in\tau$?

Comment: See the answer to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166555/does-regular-implies-collectionwise-hausdorff).